# Switch between two javascript functions

Tags: php, javascript

basically I want php to decide which version of the site pieces to load
something along the lines of:

```
    <?php 

    $sql="SELECT _1 FROM Player_Registry WHERE Player_Name = $_SESSION[user_name]"; 
    $result_1=mysql_query($sql); 
    if($result_1 < 10) { ?> 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function setdescription_1() { 
          document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = 'Alchemist'; 
        } 
      </script> 
    <?php 
    } 
    else { 
    ?> 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function setdescription_1() { 
          document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = 'Master Alchemist'; 
        } 
      </script> 
    <?php 
    }?>
```

issue is that they both run so even if I set the condition to true I still get the second.

The complete source which is identical to what is being viewed-as-source as far as I can tell but none of the php shows up in the site preview (it is actually there though because my other computer can view the site without seeing the php but when it views source it can see it which it shouldn't be able to):

```
<head>

<title>Blank</title>

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Pictures/favicon.png">

<meta name="description" content="" />

<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<meta name="author" content="" />

<meta name="owner" content="" />

<meta name="copyright" content="" />

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="TreeStyle.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>


<div style="width:100%; height:12.5%;">
    <p style="font-size: 300%;"><b>Skill Tree: Alchemist</b></p>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:75%;">
<?php
$sql="SELECT _1 FROM Player_Registry WHERE Player_Name = $_SESSION[user_name]";
$result_1=mysql_query($sql);
if($result_1 < 10)
    {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setdescription_1()
        {
        document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = 'Alchemist';
        document.getElementById('desc_box').innerHTML = 'Turn surroundings into base element costs.';
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    }
else
    {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setdescription_1()
        {
        document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = 'Master Alchemist';
        document.getElementById('desc_box').innerHTML = 'Equiped Philosopher&#39;s Stone allows bypass of element costs.';
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    }
$sql="SELECT _2 FROM Player_Registry WHERE Player_Name = $_SESSION[user_name]";
$result_2=mysql_query($sql);
if($result_2 < 10)
    {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setdescription_2()
        {
        document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = 'Learn Runes';
        document.getElementById('desc_box').innerHTML = 'Create Runes and Cores up to Lv.<?php echo "$result_2" ?>';
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    }
else
    {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setdescription_2()
        {
        document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = 'Comprehension';
        document.getElementById('desc_box').innerHTML = 'Create Runes and Cores up to Lv.10';
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    }
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function cleardescription()
        {
        document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = 'Skill Name';
        document.getElementById('desc_box').innerHTML = 'This is the skill description.';
        }
    </script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href='AddSkillPoints.php?skill=_1' onmouseover="setdescription_1()" onmouseout="cleardescription()"><img src="Alchemist.png" /></a></td>
            <td><img src="Blank_Tile.png"/></td>
            <td><a href='AddSkillPoints.php?skill=_2' onmouseover="setdescription_2()" onmouseout="cleardescription()"><img src="Learn_Runes.png"/></td>

etc..............

    </table>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; height:12.5%;">
        <b><p id="title_box" style="font-size: 150%;">Skill Name</p></b><br />
        <p id="desc_box">This is the skill description.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you get both if your PHP is actually parsed. 
If it is not parsed, you will see the code you pasted exactly as you pasted it if you look at the source of the web page

Make sure the php is parsed - if not, then that is the issue.

A script tag will generally not interfere with parsing unless you have to post processing that does not allow the tags - for example if you use some kind of framework where you are not supposed to enter php but instead some tokenised code

Here is a better example - note I moved the script to the head but did not optimise really - so the php can be more elegant if you get both values in one call and create an object array

```
<?PHP
    $sql="SELECT _1 FROM Player_Registry WHERE Player_Name = $_SESSION[user_name]";
    $result_1=mysql_query($sql);
    $sql="SELECT _2 FROM Player_Registry WHERE Player_Name = $_SESSION[user_name]";
    $result_2=mysql_query($sql);
%><html>
    <head>
    <title>Blank</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Pictures/favicon.png">
.
.
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TreeStyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var result1 = parseInt("<?PHP echo $result_1; ">,10);
    var skillLevel = (result1>=10?'Master ':'')+'Alchemist';
    var skillDesc  = result1>=10?"Equipped with Philosopher´s Stone allows bypass of element costs.":"Turn surroundings into base element costs.";

    var runeLevel  = result2>=10?'Comprehension':'Learn Runes';
    var runeDesc   = 'Create Runes and Cores up to Lv.'+result2; 

    window.onload=function() {
      setdescription_1();
    }
    function setdescription_1() {
          document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = skillLevel;
          document.getElementById('desc_box').innerHTML =  skillDesc; 
    }         
    function setdescription_2() {
          document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = runeLevel;
          document.getElementById('desc_box').innerHTML =  runeDesc; 
        }
    function cleardescription() {
            document.getElementById('title_box').innerHTML = 'Skill Name';
            document.getElementById('desc_box').innerHTML = 'This is the skill description.';
    }
        </script>



    </head>
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. That was a typo granted, but as I said in the line after the code: even if I set the conditional to true ($a < 10 replaced with true...) the result is always Hello Villian even though php you would think would toss the else statement.

Comment: I moved your comment to your question. Can you paste the view-source? It sounds like the php has not been parsed

Comment: Interestingly when I look at the source it shows that php isn't being run on this one page on my site....

Comment: looking into why that is right now... will come back with something better afterwards but right now it seems like the script tag is just killing php

Comment: Turns out httpd didn't start when I restarted my server so html files were not being read as php. My browsers just happened to be smart enough to hide the php until it hit the script tag and started reading as normal. Figured it out by renaming to php as suggested. Now I'm back to html and it all works! Many thanks.

Comment: Also thank you for the clean javascript example. I don't really know javascript so tried to use as little as possible, I also want to hide the 10 result skills but am tempted to switch to javascript based off how clean that code is.